# Non-minimally coupled inflation — expansion

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravity, field-theory, notation

In the Wikipedia article on "Inflaton" there appears the following formula:

$$S=\int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \left[\frac{1}{2}m^2_{P}R-\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\Phi\partial_{ \mu }\Phi-V(\Phi)-\frac{ 1 }{ 2}\xi R \Phi^2\right]$$
with
$\xi$ representing the strength of the interaction between
$R$ and $\phi$ which respectively relate to the curvature of space and the magnitude of the inflaton field.

Does $R$, the Ricci scalar, represent a measure of the expansion of space?

https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2995